# Travelling from Busan to Hanoi with EU passport. Do I need to show flight ticket out of Vietnam?

Tags: visas, tickets, vietnam, proof-of-onward-travel

Travelling from Busan to Hanoi with EU passport. Do I need to show flight ticket out of Vietnam?

Departing Busan, arriving in Hanoi.

I have an EU passport (Swedish). Do I need to show a flight ticket out of Vietnam at either of the airports? My plan is to fly to Hanoi and then take a bus out of the country. I do not need a visa as I have visa free entry for 14 days. But the question is if I need to show anything but the one way ticket to Hanoi.

Vesa

Answer (score 0):

If you travel Vietnam with visa free, you will need to show up your onward ticket. If you travel with Vietnam visa on arrival or e-visa, flight ticket is not required.
Try to find a bus ticket booking website and opt for booking a bus ticket online. This is considered as a proof that you will leave Vietnam after 14 days.